# How can the Kindle be used as a source code reading tool?

Tags: ipad, github, kindle

I'm a programmer.  I want to be a better programmer.  I want to read more source code written by other people (especially open source projects).  Also, I'd like to be able to have a on-hand searchable reference to all of that source code so that I can pull up reference to structures and snippets.

Does anyone know of a way to use the Kindle for this?  Has anyone tried?  What were your findings?

Additionally, does anyone know of a website that indexes all open source source code?

Comment: Doesn't the Kindle come with a built-in browser and free unlimited wireless - you could use that to browse any source code on the Internet...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: Found a good solution; see the updated section at the bottom.

I think I kind of answered part of my own question.  Thank you for the links to github and google code.

I think I'll design and mash up some solution that incorporates github, google code and the links that I found below.

I will update when I learn more.

Thank you all.

https://superuser.com/questions/73638/software-to-convert-chm-files-to-epub-kindle

http://thepugetnews.com/2008/04/29/using-google-reader-on-the-amazon-kindle/

Specifically, Reason not to #2
http://www.crunchgear.com/2009/02/25/10-reasons-to-buy-a-kindle-2-and-10-reasons-not-to/

**UPDATE:**

I've found that the ipad is much more suitable for reading source code. Now I use https://readitlaterlist.com/ and the chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bkikpncfbjndhfkipijhdoddiadaipaa

When I see articles and source code that I want to read, I mark it in my browser on my desktop with the chrome plugin. Then, when I use my ipad, I download and read the articles with ReadItLater's app. I usually have to turn off the auto-formatting as it doesn't do well with articles with source code in them.

Also, I sometimes add git repositories with the complete packages of the source code I'm reading. For example, this https://github.com/homer6/c_reading

I use safari to view and navigate through it.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of 1 site that has all open source code but you can browse through [github.com](http://github.com/) by your language and sort by popular projects.

Comment: After trying different approaches for a while, I've concluded that the Kindle isn't a good medium for reading source code. There are too many references that you need to look up when reading source code and the Kindle just insn't fast enough. I think github is the clear winner. Cloning repositories, running popular project code and understanding how it works as you hack it is extremely valuable.